# How to connect with Java to PostgreSQL 9.3 using SSPI?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, sspi

I want to connect to my local [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/) using [SSPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface). I have changed the [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file to look like for both IPv4 and IPv6 :

```
host    all             userName        127.0.0.1/32            sspi
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

When I'm trying to connect to the database using [PgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/), I don't need to specify password for the userName, whereas I need for user postgres. From this I can understand that SSPI is working.

Now, when I'm trying to validate the connection using jdbc e.g.

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbName";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
System.out.println(conn.isValid(10));
```

I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: NTDSAPI DsMakeSpn call failed with 87

Notes:

I have tried:

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbName?gsslib=sspi"
```

and

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props) //where props have only username.
```

and I also have tried this

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "userName", ""); //empty password.
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Yes. The first example is working. I was getting error because I didn't change the host file.